# Searching a two digit number in a line of a file through Sed

Tags: unix, sed

I am trying to find out a line having a two digit number in it.Eg:

test.txt

```
uuLinuxxx
Linux 2011
2011 Linux RedHat
Linux RedHat
2011
2013  2014
2010
/usr/bin
2
Ubuntu 20 world
```

Desired OP: Ubuntu 20 world

i am using

```
sed -n '/[0-9]\{2\}/p' test.txt
```

but the problem is that it is printing all the lines having 2 or more digit number.

Comment: Why didn't you try  `sed -n '/ [0-9]\{2\} /p' test.txt` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/\b[0-9]\{2\}\b/p' file
```

or:

```
sed -nr '/\b[0-9]{2}\b/p' file
```

or:

```
sed -r '\b[0-9]{2}\b/!d' file
```

or:

```
sed '/\<[0-9]\{2\}\>/!d' file
```

Comment: sed -n '/\b[0-9]\{2\}\b/p' test.txt isn't giving any output.echo $? is giving 0 as output

Comment: @Shashank this is probably specific to GNU sed however see the last edit.

Answer (score 2):

Use `-w` switch to match word (in your case digits).

```
grep -w '[0-9][0-9]' file
```

From `man` page:

```
-w, --word-regexp
     Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words.  
     The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the
     line,  or preceded by a non-word constituent character. Similarly, it must be either 
     at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character. Word-
     constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your regular expression is looking for two consecutive digits, which exist is the numbers `20` (good) and `99999999999999999999` (not so good).

What you need is a regular expression ensuring that there are no digits on either side of the two you find, such as:

```
[^0-9][0-9]{2}[^0-9]  # non-digit the two digits then non-digit
```

In addition, you need to trap those where the two digits are at the start or end of the line (or the only thing on the line). So you need multiple regular expressions separated by the or conjunction `|` or as separate `-e` arguments:

```
^[0-9]{2}[^0-9]       # at start of line
[^0-9][0-9]{2}[^0-9]  # in middle of line
[^0-9][0-9]{2}$       # at end of line
^[0-9]{2}[^0-9]$      # only thing on line
```

You may also want to choose a better tool for the job, such as `grep`. Using the slightly modified input file:

```
uuLinuxxx
Linux 2011
2011 Linux RedHat
Linux RedHat
2011
2013  2014
2010
/usr/bin
2
Ubuntu 20 world
99 at the start
at the end: 99
88
```

the following command (split for readability):

```
grep -E -e '[^0-9][0-9]{2}[^0-9]'
        -e '^[0-9]{2}[^0-9]'
        -e '[^0-9][0-9]{2}$'
        -e '^[0-9]{2}[^0-9]$' test.txt
```

gives you what you want:

```
Ubuntu 20 world
99 at the start
at the end: 99
88
```

---

Of course, if you have GNU `grep` with its Perl-based regular expressions, and you're after "words" which are two-digit numbers, this becomes much easier:

```
grep -P '\b\d{2}\b' test.txt
```

but, if you can guarantee that word restriction, the following will also work:

```
grep -Ew '[0-9]{2}' test.txt
```

Comment: There's an easier way: `egrep '[0-9]{2}' | grep -v '[0-9]{3}'`. Assuming we don't want lines like '50 something 500'.

Comment: @aragaer, that's not going to work for a line containing `"300 mm is the same as 30 cm"` but, if you can guarantee only one number per line, it might be an option. But still, I suspect the `grep -P` is the better way to go.

Comment: If numbers are "words", we can use `egrep -w '[0-9]{2}'` instead.

Comment: @Shashank, then your `egrep` is deficient. What does `egrep --version` give you?

Comment: @paxdiablo: VERSION:  11.10.0

Comment: @Shashank, that's a strange output (unless you're running HPUX) - which OS are you actually running? I would suggest getting a copy of GNU grep if possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n 's/.*/²&²/;/[^0-9][0-9]\{2\}[^0-9]/ s/.\(.*\)./\1/p' YourFile
```

Using a temporary border to allow only 1 check for extraction of the line with a 2 digit only number inside

Comment: What's ²&² ?? Never seen this before . How to write it through keyboard  :(

Comment: ² is a square character and arbitrary used because not often in string but any other char is ok until it is not in the string to treat. This char is on my keyboard but lot of extended ascii char are in the same case